# Django blog. Why is part of the html not showing on all pages?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I am using django  to create a blog where all posts are shown on the home page as well as on pages depending on their subject.  While the basics as shown work, I am having difficulty with the following:

This part of base.html is repeated on each page:

```
<h1><a href="/">DR SMART.INFO</a></h1>
    <p>the web site for the analytical rugby fan</p>
```

However this part only shows on index.html and not on other pages eg subject.html or post_detail.html

```
<p>
      <ul>
        {% for subject in subjects %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'subject' subject.subject_slug %}">{{ subject }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul> 
    </p>
```

I would like it to show on the top of each page.

Thanks for assistance with this.
Roderic

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>drsmart.info</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1><a href="/">DR SMART.INFO</a></h1>
    <p>the web site for the analytical rugby fan</p>
    <p>
      <ul>
        {% for subject in subjects %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'subject' subject.subject_slug %}">{{ subject }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul> 
    </p>
    
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {% for post in posts %}
    <div>
      <h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      <p>author: {{post.author}}, published: {{post.date_added }}</p>
      <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

subject.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>{{ subject }}</h2>
      {% for post in posts %}
          {% if post.subject == subject %}
          <div>
            <h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p>author: {{post.author}}, published: {{post.date_added }}</p>
            <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
          </div>
          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="post">
    {% if post.date_added %}
      <div class="date">
        {{ post.date_added }}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="comments_section">
  {{ comments.count }} comments
    
  {% for comment in comments %}
    <div class="comments">
      {{ comment.name }}
      {{ comment.made_on }}
      {{ comment.body | linebreaks }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="comments_section">
  {% if new_comment %}
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    Your comment is awaiting moderation
    </div>
  {% else %}
    Your views? All fields are required. Your email address will not be published.
  <form method="post">
    {{ comment_form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
  {% endif %}
  </div>    

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you pass `subjects` into the context when you render all of these templates?

Comment: Thanks Abdul, I added:  subjects = Subject.objects.all() to each view and in each return render of that view I included:  'subjects': subjects,  All now works!

Comment: Do check [Writing your own context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) if this variable needs to be passed in **all templates**. It would be very helpful to you considering it would be tedious to remember otherwise.